# Lagrange Multipliers for Implicit Functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, implicit-differentiation

How can I find the minimum / maximum of a function for one variable defined implicitly (f(x, y, z) = c) with a constraint g(x, y) = c on the domain?

For example, say you wanted to minimize for z:

$$-4\,x\,y^2\,z^3+2\,y^3\,z^2+x^3\,y^5+5\,x\,y^4=3$$

given that the xy coordinates lie on the unit circle:

$$x^2+y^2=1$$

How would this be done? Is it even possible?

Comment: What do you mean you want to minimize $f(x,y,z)=c$? Isn't that its value has been fixed already?

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer. It made more sense in my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function $F(x,y,z)=z$ and minimize it subject to the *two* constraints you have. Writing the constraints as $f=3$ and $g=1$, you want two Lagrange multipliers, $\lambda$ and $\mu$. Solve for where the constraints hold along with $$\nabla F =\lambda\nabla f + \mu\nabla g.$$

Comment: In my example, what would F(x, y, z) = z be? Wouldn't this just be another implicit function in disguise, since you could define h(x, y, z) = F(x, y, z) - z such that you would just have another constraint h(x, y, z) = 0?

Comment: Oh! I just realized! The implicit function was a constraint and the value I was maximizing was z! That makes sense, thank you (also sorry for not being able to give you an upvote)